# How do I specify S3 key with wild card while searching in Scala Spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have a scala spark code that writes a json file with file name as `part-*.json` for example (part-00000-14732361-f017-468a-b948-22d3b6d460dc-c000.json).

I want to do
`s3.doesObjectExist(buckey, key)` where `bucket = xyz` and `key = abc/def/part-*.json`.

Looks like s3 doesn't support wildcard search. What is the best way for me to do
s3.doesObjectExist(buckey, key) when I don't know the exact file name in S3? There is always only one such json file stored as `part-*.json`.

Please help thanks!

Comment: How did it go? is it still unclear that AWS does not support what you want to do directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround

```
val bucket = "xyz"
val fileNamePrefix = "abc/def/part"
val key = s3.listObjectsV2(bucket,fileNamePrefix).getObjectSummaries.get(0).getKey
```

Since I mentioned there only one such file, the above code helped me get the entire key with full file name that I use.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to do it with AWS API. You have to download the list of objects yourself and do the filtering on your own side. If you have lots of objects, you can request [S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html) to get the list and filter that.